# How to count the number of entries in a row and reset when a field changes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of emails each user opens in a row. I have the data sorted by email address and date and can count the # opened in a row, but I can't figure out how to get it to reset to 0 when there's a new email address.

This is what I have so far. This does count the number opened in a row, but it doesn't reset to 0 when there's a new email address.

```
in_a_row = []
count = 0

for row in merge['Opened?']:
    if row == 1:
        count += 1
        in_a_row.append(count)
    elif row == 0:
        count = 0
        in_a_row.append(count)
merged['in_a_row'] = in_a_row
```

Here's what it currently looks like

```
Index   email_address   sent_date      sent_rank  Opened?   in_a_row
0   email_A@gmail.com   5/15/2018          1          1         1
1   email_A@gmail.com   5/23/2018          2          0         0
2   email_A@gmail.com   5/23/2018          3          1         1
3   email_B@gmail.com   5/26/2018          1          1         2
4   email_B@gmail.com   5/27/2018          2          1         3
5   email_B@gmail.com   8/2/2018           3          0         0
6   email_B@gmail.com   8/3/2018           4          1         1
7   email_B@gmail.com   12/12/2018         5          1         2
8   email_C@gmail.com   12/12/2018         1          1         3
9   email_C@gmail.com   2/6/2019           2          0         0
10  email_C@gmail.com   2/12/2019          3          1         1
```

This is what it should look like

```
Index   email_address   sent_date      sent_rank  Opened?   in_a_row
0   email_A@gmail.com   5/15/2018          1          1         1
1   email_A@gmail.com   5/23/2018          2          0         0
2   email_A@gmail.com   5/23/2018          3          1         1
3   email_B@gmail.com   5/26/2018          1          1         1
4   email_B@gmail.com   5/27/2018          2          1         2
5   email_B@gmail.com   8/2/2018           3          0         0
6   email_B@gmail.com   8/3/2018           4          1         1
7   email_B@gmail.com   12/12/2018         5          1         2
8   email_C@gmail.com   12/12/2018         1          1         1
9   email_C@gmail.com   2/6/2019           2          0         0
10  email_C@gmail.com   2/12/2019          3          1         1
```

Comment: I don't get the logic of the first change from 1 to 0 in `in_a_row`. Is it not a new address?

Comment: When `Opened?` goes from 1 to 0 at the same `email_address` the counter resets as well?

Comment: Another question, why do all Email addresses start counting at `0` but the first email address starts at `1`?

Comment: It looks like there were some typos in the tables, sorry about that, they should be fixed now. When Opened? = 0, it means the email was unopened, when Opened? = 1 it means it was opened. The counter should always reset to 0 when an email is unopened, but it should also reset to 0 when there's a new email address.

Comment: are the `email_address` always clustered together in that manner? i.e. is it possible to see email_A@gmail.com after email_C@gmail.com in row 11 or 12?

Comment: @AdityaSantoso the dataframe is sorted by email_address and sent_date, so you wouldn't see email_A in any rows after it ends.

Comment: I believe some of the `in_a_row` values in the expected output are a little off... eg row `3` & `4` should be `1, 2` respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with a lambda using [`.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`), [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), [`.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
g = df.groupby('email_address')
df['in_a_row'] = g['Opened?'].transform(lambda x: x * (x.groupby((x.ne(x.shift())).cumsum()).cumcount().add(x)))
```

*Note: I think there might still be some typo's in your desired output. eg, idx `8` and `9` input and output have different values for `Opened?`*

---

[output]

```
    Index      email_address   sent_date  sent_rank  Opened?  in_a_row
0       0  email_A@gmail.com   5/15/2018          1        1         1
1       1  email_A@gmail.com   5/23/2018          2        0         0
2       2  email_A@gmail.com   5/23/2018          3        1         1
3       3  email_B@gmail.com   5/26/2018          1        1         1
4       4  email_B@gmail.com   5/27/2018          2        1         2
5       5  email_B@gmail.com    8/2/2018          3        0         0
6       6  email_B@gmail.com    8/3/2018          4        1         1
7       7  email_B@gmail.com  12/12/2018          5        1         2
8       8  email_C@gmail.com  12/12/2018          1        1         1
9       9  email_C@gmail.com    2/6/2019          2        0         0
10     10  email_C@gmail.com   2/12/2019          3        1         1
```

Comment: This is really close. It does work for the sample data, but when I applied it to the larger data set it looks like there are exceptions the sample data didn't account for. I updated index 5 so there's an example of when it's not working. Now that Opened? at index 5 is equal to 0, in_a_row at index 6 should be 0, but instead it's 2. Also, you were right about the typos, thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Tim344. will have a look into it

Comment: @Tim344 updated my answer if you want to give it a go again?